# Why is there a python syntax error while creating this dictionary, it is pointing at the ":"

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax-error

Where is the error in this?

```
states = [
    'Oregon' : 'OR',  
    'Florida' : 'FL',  
    'California' : 'CA',  
    'New York' : 'NY',  
    'Michigan' : 'MI'  
]
```

It is telling me that the error is the : between 'Oregon' and 'OR'.  If i comment out that line, it says the same thing for the next line.  I am thoroughly confuzed.

Answer (score 6):

A python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is represented with `{` and `}` and not `[]`

```
states = { 'Oregon' : 'OR',
    'Florida' : 'FL',
    'California' : 'CA',
    'New York' : 'NY',
    'Michigan' : 'MI'
}
```

is a valid dictionary